# Transport stream processing in Openmax al

Tags: openmax

I am trying to understand the flow of audio/video in **OpenMAX AL**.I have the following doubts.

**According to my understanding the audio/video flow goes like:**

From the android application the **mpeg2** stream goes to **OpenMAX AL** which gives it to soc where the stream is given to **demux**. Then video stream goes to decoding, then preprocessing, then it is rendered to surface/surface texture for display. Audio stream after **demuxing**-->**decoding** goes to audio output device.

1. what kind of effects/processing OpenMAX AL applies on mpeg2 transport stream.
2. how **opensl** is different from OpenMAX AL audio. at
3. It renders the stream to demuxer-->through AudioSink, VideoSink(little confused here). if it directly gives to AudioSink/ VideoSink where it is **demuxed** and decoded.
4. what is the input module in OpenMAX AL i.e where it received **mpeg2ts** and gives it for processing.

**Regards

Mayank**

Comment: Are there any google experts to answer to this question ?